# Guice: Intercepting method with params and fields

Tags: java, annotations, aop, guice

Im looking into intercepting method invocations with Guice. I saw from [here](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/AOP) that basic interceptions are possible. However, the logic intercepting the methods require access to not only the parameters passed into the function, but also (unfortunately) a class member property. Is it possible to achieve this with Guice AOP? If so, what needs to be done? I'm thinking of something that might look like this:

```
class Foo {
    @customInterceptor Object member; // Intercepting logic needs this

    // function to be intercepted, param needed for the logic as well
    @customInterceptor
    void myFunc(@customInterceptor String param) {
        // body, do something with member and param
    }
}
```

Comment: If you need reflection to access a private field, that’s usually a sign that you have a class with too much responsibility. (Obviously, there are exceptions, such as a reflective serializer.) If you provide some more details (is the private field a supporting object or is it internal state? What sort of interceptor is it?) I can try to recommend a way to avoid accessing a private field.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using reflection. Not sure if it is a good practice and I assume you know what you are doing!

```
public Object invoke(MethodInvocation methodInvocation) throws Throwable {
    Object o = methodInvocation.getThis();
    Field f = methodInvocation.getMethod().getDeclaringClass().getDeclaredField("member");
    //if member is private
    f.setAccessible(true);
    System.out.println("inside interception :: " + f.get(o));
    f.setAccessible(false);
    return methodInvocation.proceed();
}
```